# Compare File with ignore some line/last line

Tags: python

We have two log files in which one is generated from a process. We compare one file(golden file) to another file to check if file correct or not. It should have same value. We generally use diff utility to compare two files. I have got enhancement to add machine information into process generated File. So I want to compare upto previous line and ignore  new changes.
Could Anyone provide me any utility which I can use in python.

Golden File

```
CMD gen -vdd 0.99 -vss 0 -sinps 0.02 -slew 0.1 -temp -40 -rise -data
CMD gen -vdd 0.99 -vss 0 -sinps 0.06 -slew 0.1 -temp -40 -rise -clock
CMD gen -vdd 0.99 -vss 0 -sinps 0.02 -slew 0.1 -temp -40 -fall -data
CMD gen -vdd 0.99 -vss 0 -sinps 0.02 -slew 0.1 -temp -40 -fall -data
CMD gen -vdd 0.99 -vss 0 -sinps 0.06 -slew 0.1 -temp -40 -rise -clock
CMD gen -vdd 0.99 -vss 0 -sinps 0.02 -slew 0.1 -temp -40 -rise -data
Temp1   Temp2   Temp3   Temp4   Temp5   Temp6
-31.00     -19.00      -3.00       -8.00      43.00      61.00
```

Process File

```
CMD gen -vdd 0.99 -vss 0 -sinps 0.02 -slew 0.1 -temp -40 -rise -data
CMD gen -vdd 0.99 -vss 0 -sinps 0.06 -slew 0.1 -temp -40 -rise -clock
CMD gen -vdd 0.99 -vss 0 -sinps 0.02 -slew 0.1 -temp -40 -fall -data
CMD gen -vdd 0.99 -vss 0 -sinps 0.02 -slew 0.1 -temp -40 -fall -data
CMD gen -vdd 0.99 -vss 0 -sinps 0.06 -slew 0.1 -temp -40 -rise -clock
CMD gen -vdd 0.99 -vss 0 -sinps 0.02 -slew 0.1 -temp -40 -rise -data
Temp1   Temp2   Temp3   Temp4   Temp5   Temp6
-31.00     -19.00      -3.00       -8.00      43.00      61.00
 Adding machine name( ignore machine name)
```

I have write code in following.Can we better way for improve code

```
data = None
with open("Golden_File",'r+') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
del data[-1]

data_1 = None
with open("cp.log",'r+') as f:
    data_1 = f.readlines()
del data_1[-1]
print cmp(data, data_1)
```

[Question]: Does cmp function works fine in list also. I have used first time and not sure how internally works.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to compare the 2 files after deleting the last line from `Process File`. Correct? If correct then why are you deleting the last line in data. Wouldn't that delete the last line from what you have read from the `Golden File`?

Comment: `cmp` does indeed work for lists - see http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types and http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp. But you could just as easily type `print data == data_1`

Comment: @AseemBansal, correct Ya I am planning to remove last line from golden also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind reading the entire files into memory at once (as you are currently doing), you can just compare them as lists of lines:

```
with open("Golden_File", "r") as golden, open("cp.log", "r") as log:
    if golden.readlines() == log.readlines()[:-1]:
        print "files match"
```

Otherwise you can use `itertools` and compare one line at a time:

```
from itertools import izip
with open("Golden_File", "r") as golden, open("cp.log", "r") as log:
    lines_match = all(a == b for a, b in izip(golden, log))
    one_line_left = len(list(log)) == 1 and list(golden) == []
    if lines_match and one_line_left:
        print "files match"
```

Comment: Agree, But As I am doing operation on the last line. And I know only last line will be change than it will be overhead for me

Comment: Not sure what you mean - one way or another, you have to read the whole file in. If you don't need to check that there is a remaining line in the log file, you can remove  `one_line_left = ...` and just check whether `lines_match` is true.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for python here, you can use the `head` command to filter out the last line of a file:

```
diff <(head -n -1 "Golden_File") <(head -n -1 "cp.log")
```